# Multiple THEN statements in Tcl IF statement

Tags: if-statement, tcl

I'm working with a Tcl script and want to do two separate things if an if statement is true. Code is below:

```
if { $Start_day >= 1 && $Start_day <= 15} {set Meteo_file "edas.$Start_month2$Start_year.001"                                                                                                                                            
                                           set Meteo_file_back "edas.$Start_month2_back$Start_year_back.002"}
```

However, I error out and get this:

```
wrong # args: should be "set varName ?newValue?"
while executing
"set Meteo_file "edas.$Start_month2$Start_year.001" 
set Meteo_file_back "edas.$Start_month2_back$Start_year_back.002""
```

Is there any way (syntax) to have an if statement do two separate things when it comes true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be more readable IMO to have them on separate lines:

```
if {$Start_day >= 1 && $Start_day <= 15} {
    set Meteo_file "edas.$Start_month2$Start_year.001"
    set Meteo_file_back "edas.$Start_month2_back$Start_year_back.002"
}
```

And I cannot get your error... The above works fine for me.

As a side note, could it be that you're using both `set` on the same line? I don't see why there'd be a lot of whitespaces to the right of the first `set` otherwise.

Comment: Maybe it was just a spacing issue on my part because this works. Thank you!

Comment: @DJV Awesome then! Glad to have helped :)